# Flutter: Scroll between multiple Listviews (NestedScrollView and GroupedListView)

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies

I currently investigate that it's not possible to scroll through the nest scroll view into the groupedlistview.

It Stucks in the grouped list view.

A short video Demo: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Zf3GnYSAnUD2W3FX2cN1p9SxUMtig1Pg/view?usp=sharing

After the half in the video I removed the NeverScrollableScrollPhysics from the GroupedListView

The GroupedListView

```
GroupedListView<dynamic, String>(
                  shrinkWrap: true,
                  elements: getGoldenMoment(controller.filterModel.value.nameStartsWith ?? '').sections!,
                  groupBy: (element) => element['name'],
                  useStickyGroupSeparators: true,
                  groupSeparatorBuilder: (String groupByValue) => Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 8.0, horizontal: 20),
                    child: Text(groupByValue, style: AppTextStyle.titleMedium(),),
                  ),
                  itemBuilder: (context, element) {
                    return FutureBuilder(
                        future: articleService.getArticles(filterModel: FilterModel(nameStartsWith: element['name']), maxItems: 4, loadSize: 4),
                        builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<List<ArticleModel>> articlesSnapshot) {
                          if (articlesSnapshot.data == null) {
                            return const SizedBox();
                          }
                          return ListView.builder(primary: false, shrinkWrap: true, physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(), itemBuilder: (context, index){
                              controller.contextMap[element['name']] = context;
                            return index == 3 ? InkWell(onTap: () => controller.continueSearch(element['name']), child: Center(child: Text('Mehr ansehen', style: AppTextStyle.titleMedium(underline: true, color: AppColors.primary),))) : tileListItem(articleModel: articlesSnapshot.data![index], showFavoriteButton: true);
                          }, itemCount: articlesSnapshot.data!.length,);
                          return const SizedBox();
                        }
                    );
                  },)
```

The NestedScrollView Code:

```
NestedScrollView(
key: controller.nestedKey,
floatHeaderSlivers: true,
headerSliverBuilder: (context, innerBoxIsScrolled) => [
  SliverAppBar(
    floating: true,
    snap: true,
    pinned: true,
    forceElevated: true,
    // expandedHeight: size+50,
    leading: IconButton(icon: Icon(Icons.chevron_left, color: Colors.black,), onPressed: () => controller.back(),),
    centerTitle: true,
    title: Text('Suche', style: AppTextStyle.medium(),),
    bottom: PreferredSize(
      preferredSize: Size.fromHeight(size),
      child: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: [
          SizedBox(height: 10,),
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20),
            child: Row(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              children: [
                Expanded(
                  child: textFormFieldShadowComponentWithAutoCompletion(
                      clearFunction: true,
                      onIconClick: () => FocusManager.instance.primaryFocus!.unfocus(),
                      onClear: (){
                        FocusManager.instance.primaryFocus!.unfocus();
                        FilterModel fm = controller.filter;
                        fm.nameStartsWith = "";
                        controller.filter = fm;
                      },
                      trailing: InkWell(
                        onTap: () => controller.openMap(),
                        child: Container(
                            padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 14, right: 10),
                            child: Icon(Icons.map_outlined, color: AppColors.tertiary,)),
                      ),
                      label: "Suche",
                      textEditingController: TextEditingController(text: controller.filterModel.value.nameStartsWith),
                      validator: notEmptyValidator,
                      onSubmit: (_){
                        mixpanel.track(MixPanelEvents.searchTitle.name, properties: {'title': _});
                        controller.savedArticles.clear();
                        controller.filterModel.value = controller.filterModel.value.copy();
                        controller.filterModel.value.nameStartsWith = _;
                        controller.filterModel.refresh();
                        controller.load();
                        controller.nestedKey.currentState!.innerController.jumpTo(0);
                        controller.nestedKey.currentState!.outerController.jumpTo(0);
                      },
                      // onChanged: (_){
                      //   controller.filterModel.value.nameStartsWith = _;
                      //   controller.filterModel.refresh();
                      //   // FilterModel fm = controller.filter;
                      //   // fm.nameStartsWith = _;
                      //   // controller.filter = fm;
                      // },
                      icon: Icon(Icons.search)),
                ),
                SizedBox(width: 10,),
                InkWell(
                  onTap: () => controller.navigateToFilter(),
                  child: Container(
                    height: 45,
                    width: 45,
                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.white, borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10), boxShadow: [
                      BoxShadow(
                          color: Colors.black.withOpacity(.10),
                          blurRadius: 3,
                          spreadRadius: 2,
                          offset: const Offset(0, 3))
                    ]),
                    child: SvgPicture.asset(IconVectorPath.filterVector, color: AppColors.tertiary,),
                  ),
                )
              ],
            ),
          ),
          SizedBox(height: 10,),
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20),
            child: SingleChildScrollView(
              scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
              child: Row(
                children: [
                  if((controller.filterModel.value.minPrice != null && controller.filterModel.value.minPrice != 0) && controller.filterModel.value.maxPrice == null)
                    filterWidget(title: 'ab ${controller.filterModel.value.minPrice}€', onRemove: () => controller.filterModel.value.minPrice = null),
                  if(controller.filterModel.value.maxPrice != null && (controller.filterModel.value.minPrice == null || controller.filterModel.value.minPrice == 0))
                    filterWidget(title: 'bis ${controller.filterModel.value.maxPrice}€', onRemove: () => controller.filterModel.value.maxPrice = null),
                  if(controller.filterModel.value.maxPrice != null && (controller.filterModel.value.minPrice != null && controller.filterModel.value.minPrice != 0))
                    filterWidget(title: '${controller.filterModel.value.minPrice} - ${controller.filterModel.value.maxPrice}€', onRemove: () => {controller.filterModel.value.maxPrice = null, controller.filterModel.value.minPrice = null}),
                  if(controller.filterModel.value.startDay != null && controller.filterModel.value.endDay != null)
                    filterWidget(title: '${controller.filterModel.value.startDay!.day}.${controller.filterModel.value.startDay!.month} - ${controller.filterModel.value.endDay!.day}.${controller.filterModel.value.endDay!.month}', onRemove: () => {controller.filterModel.value.startDay = null, controller.filterModel.value.endDay = null}),
                  if(controller.filterModel.value.radius != null && controller.filterModel.value.location != null)
                    filterWidget(title: '${(controller.filterModel.value.radius!/1000).toInt()}km Umkreis', onRemove: () => {controller.filterModel.value.radius = null, controller.filterModel.value.location = null}),
                  if(controller.filterModel.value.categories != null && controller.filterModel.value.categories!.isNotEmpty)
                    SizedBox(
                      height: 37,
                      child: ListView.builder(scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal, shrinkWrap: true, itemBuilder: (context, index){
                        return filterWidget(title: controller.filterModel.value.categories![index].name.capitalize!, onRemove: () {
                          controller.filterModel.value.categories!.removeWhere((element) => element.name == controller.filterModel.value.categories![index].name);
                          if(controller.filterModel.value.categories!.isEmpty){
                            controller.filterModel.value.categories = null;
                        }
                        });
                      }, itemCount: controller.filterModel.value.categories!.length,),
                    )
                ],),
            ),
          ),
          const SizedBox(height: 10),
          Container(height: 1, color: Colors.black.withOpacity(.2),)
        ],
      ),
    ),

  )
],
body: body(),
```

)

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not much clear but I assume you are looking for this.

To achieve scrolling to the bottom, regardless of other horizontally scrolling views, you can follow these steps:

1. Wrap your content inside a Column widget.
2. Place the Column inside a SingleChildScrollView.
3. For vertically scrolling ListView widgets, set shrinkWrap to true
   and use NeverScrollableScrollPhysics to prevent them from scrolling.
4. If you have used Expanded or Flexible widgets to size ListViews
   please remove them.

**Example**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class ScrollBottom extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Bottom Scroll Example'),
      ),
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            ListView.builder(
              shrinkWrap: true,
              physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
              itemCount: 10, // your item count
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                return ListTile(
                  title: Text('Item $index'),
                );
              },
            ),
            ListView.builder(
              shrinkWrap: true,
              physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
              itemCount: 20, 
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                return ListTile(
                  title: Text('Item2 $index'),
                );
              },
            ),
        
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```